# How to perform a scroll Up action till finding out the elements looking out for using espresso

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

I'm new to espresso and I want to scroll to the top of the screen until the element not found. How to do this in espresso? Need some help here.

Comment: You want to scroll to an element? What does it means, like if you have a list of [1,2,3,4,5,6] you want to scroll to element 4 and then do perform a click for instance?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS - No, I am not on the list. I am trying to automate an email compose screen where I am bottom of the compose screen and I want to scroll to the top to click on Send button (Whereas send button is not visible in the view. It will appear until I do some scroll action in the view). How to achieve this?

Comment: Ahhh, that's easier then, let me help you ...

Answer (score 1):

> I want to scroll to the top to click on Send button. How to achieve this?

It's not necessary to scroll to the top, you can also use `scrollTo`, which is a method already defined by `ViewAction` class of `Espresso`.

```
 public static ViewAction scrollTo() {
    return actionWithAssertions(new ScrollToAction());
  }
```

You also must check this to make it work.

```
/**
   * Returns an action that scrolls to the view.<br>
   * <br>
   * View preconditions:
   *
   * <ul>
   *   <li>must be a descendant of ScrollView
   *   <li>must have visibility set to View.VISIBLE
   *       <ul>
   */
```

So, what you have to do? First know the id of the `Button` or whatever `View`, to do that you can simply use  :

`onView(withId(R.id.yourButtonId))`

Ok, then what you have to do is perform a `scrollTo()`, then you do it like this :

`onView(withId(R.id.yourButtonId)).perform(ViewActions.scrollTo())`

And then it should go to the element doing a scroll.

Finally if you want to click to that `View` you can add action(s) on `perform()` method as you can see here :

```
/**
   * Performs the given action(s) on the view selected by the current view matcher. If more than one
   * action is provided, actions are executed in the order provided with precondition checks running
   * prior to each action.
   *
   * @param viewActions one or more actions to execute.
   * @return this interaction for further perform/verification calls.
   */
```

So to do a click is as easy as write `click()` then the final code should be

`onView(withId(R.id.yourButtonId)).perform(ViewActions.scrollTo(), ViewActions.click())`